# GIT Synchronizing with origin/master asks credentials twice, VS Code, Ubuntu

Tags: git, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

As stated in the title, I use Ubuntu, and VS Code for editing my project and GIT for version control.

I picked VS Team services to host my code base.

Whenever synchronizing changes with the remote hosting, the dialog will ask for my credentials twice, before executing the operation. (I'm performing the sync from within VS Code.) Why is this and how can I get around it.

Disclaimer: I'm quite new to Linux, GIT and VS Code, so please accept my apologies if this is lame.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio Code asks twice when you hit the synchronize button because when synchronizing, both pull and push are executed. For each one of those two operations you need to confirm that it is you who wants to change repository data.